# バーチャルスティックがスマホのブラウザ上で実行した時、指を放しても中央に戻らない

Tags: unity3d, webgl

UnityでOn-screen sticksを使って画面に二つのスティックを表示しています（移動と視点回転）。
WebGLで出力し、スマホのブラウザで実行しました。
基本的に問題なく動いているのですが、両方のスティックを同時に触って同時に放すと、スティックが中央に戻らない時があります。（動き続ける）

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631
こちらのアセットを使った場合も同様のことが起きてるので、タッチイベント的な問題のような気がするのですが･･･

対処法はないでしょうか。
指を放したスティックが中央に戻ってほしいということです。

Unityのバージョンは2021.2.17f1
AndroidのChoromeでも、iPadのSafariでも同様の現象が起きてます。

Answer (score 1):

Unity の WebGL ってスマホのブラウザはサポートしてなかったと思います。もし最近サポートされたというならすみません。その場合はその情報ソースを教えてもらえると後学のためになりありがたいです。

以下は「サポートされていない」という情報のソースです。

[Unity User Manual - WebGL のブラウザー間での互換性](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2021.1/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html)

> Unity WebGL コンテンツは現在モバイル端末ではサポートされていないことに注意してください。

どうしてそのような動きをするかについては、サポートされていないので Unity Technologies でテストしていないのでしょう。推測ですが、内部的に「タッチ」特に「マルチタッチ」の機能がなくて、全て「マウスボタン」で内部処理されているのではないかと思います。「マウスボタン」で処理しているなら、マウスボタンが複数の箇所で同時に押されることはないので、おかしな動きになってしまうこともあると思います。

どうすればいいか、ですがそれはサポートしている方法で要件を満たすように工夫する、というのが普通の解決方法です。スマホで動かしたいのであればスマホアプリを作るとか、ブラウザゲームでなければいけないならスマホはサポートしない、とかです。他には、スマホブラウザのマルチタッチをサポートしている別のゲームエンジンを使うなどです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
正式に対応されたかは分かりませんが「動いている」というのが現状です。
少し前のバージョンまでは「サポートしてない」的な英語のメッセージが表示されていましたが、少なくとも2021.2.17f1でビルドしたものは何の表示もされなく動作しています。